# Consistent error in GPS results - can I use this to my advantage?

Tags: gps

I recently bought a SparkFun RTK Express GPS unit and I've been enjoying figuring it out.  I can now talk geoids and ellipsoid models without sounding like a complete idiot.

There are several NGS stations near my house, and for practice I've been setting up the GPS directly over the pins and then seeing where the unit thinks I am.  I'm noticing there's a consistent pattern - the unit will start out 150-200 cm to the northwest of the actual position and over the next 5-8 minutes will get closer and closer until it ends up 30-40 cm NNW of the actual position, which seems like that's really the best you can do with one unit (the company keeps trying to sell me a second unit, plus antennas, radios, etc.).

But is this consistent error (30-40 cm NNW of actual) something I could use?  In other words, is this error indicative of some component in the GPS that doesn't have the exact specs it should (some resistor is 1% too high, or the clock is 0.0001% slow, that kind of thing), and I can then guess that when I'm trying to locate some point that doesn't have an NGS pin under it, that the actual point will be 1 foot SSE of where the GPS thinks it is?  Or is this seeming pattern something I shouldn't rely on at all?

[image: First GPS]
[image: Second GPS]
[image: Third GPS]

Comment: Do you have an antenna for this device., possible calibrate required.

Comment: Yes it comes with a GNSS Multi-Band L1/L2 Surveying Antenna.  Calibration makes sense, but in my dealings with the company they've never mentioned it as something I would need to do, I'll reach out to them and ask about that.https://www.sparkfun.com/products/18380

Comment: Here is some good info for Site Calibration and using a 2m Antenna https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hojgy4K3t_c  (Trimble R10 and a TSC7) but the principle is the same.

Comment: Alas, that video is for a setup that costs 10x or 20x what my budget will allow.  I'm not using a professional-grade surveying application, I'm using a free app named "SW Maps".  Are there any apps that don't cost an arm and a leg that a weekend hobbyist could use?

Comment: with a limited budget I would focus on Dual Band GNSS Chipsets/devices (your device is both L1C/A and L2C bands) but L1/L5 will get you sub-meter accuracy with good satellite fixes.

Comment: I don't have experience with u-Blox ZED-F9P, but I've used earlier u-blox, I suspect that a consistent 30-40 cm offset (assuming it really is consistent) is a datum or epoch problem rather than a GPS component error.  It would be useful if you could convince someone with a Mapping or Survey GNSS to capture the same pins, using the same NGS base station corrections you've been using.  I'd also try not to convert between WGS-84 and NAD83, various applications make various mistakes when doing that. . .

Answer (score 0):

After hearing from @Trams and @Mapperz, I thought the best thing to do would be to grab more data.

There's an NGS marker named "Happy Jack", the NGS database lists this information:

```
LL1418* NAD 83(2011) POSITION- 40 06 46.34217(N) 105 05 01.90508(W)   ADJUSTED  
LL1418* NAD 83(2011) ELLIP HT-  1537.259 (meters)        (06/27/12)   ADJUSTED
LL1418* NAD 83(2011) EPOCH   -  2010.00
```

Entering these values into the NGS converter:

```
HTDP OUTPUT, VERSION 3.4.0   
TRANSFORMING POSITIONS FROM NAD_83(2011/CORS96/2007) (EPOCH = 01-01-2010 (2010.0000))
                      TO WGS84(G2139)             (EPOCH = 10-14-2022 (2022.7836))
LATITUDE     40 06 46.34217 N     40 06 46.36008 N        0.57 mm/yr  north
LONGITUDE   105 05  1.90508 W    105 05  1.95838 W        1.90 mm/yr  east
ELLIP. HT.            1537.259            1536.392 m     -1.20 mm/yr  up
X                 -1271448.929        -1271449.882 m      2.17 mm/yr
Y                 -4717481.664        -4717480.352 m      0.75 mm/yr
Z                  4088568.850         4088568.713 m     -0.34 mm/yr
```

So the expected position will be 40.11287780, -105.08387733

I figured out how to enable logging inside of SW Maps, and then figured out how to extract the lat/lon from the UBX file, so I can now plot the GPS position 4x/second.  Putting all that together, here's what it looked like as I set up the RTK and waited 10 minutes:

[image: All GPS Values]

Since the unit claims its results are accurate to within 30 cm (about a foot for those of us stuck with imperial units), I had Excel draw a circle at a radius of 30 cm around the converted NGS position.

You can see that the unit started out 5 or 6 feet off, started figuring things out, got a little confused after 6 or 7 minutes in, but starting at about 7.5 minutes it settled in and from then on stayed well within its stated accuracy.

HOWEVER

Back to my original question - in this case, the RTK was off by about 4" to the west, rather than the 12" to the north I had been seeing before.  That means that the 12" errors I was seeing with my first few measurements were not due to something inherent to the RTK itself, but rather something in the more complicated ecosystem that will change day to day and location to location.

So the answer to my question is "since there isn't a consistent error in the results, you can't use that to improve the accuracy of those results"